# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\rimdetails' not found?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have created a laravel project with Rims and tyres. when clicking a Rim from the index page, i would like to link directly to a rim detail page, like a productdetails page based on the clicked product.

So far, it seems that my route and blade files are fine! but i have no idea how to make the controller function. i have tried with:

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $rimdetails = rimdetails::with('rimdetails')->findOrFail($id);
        return View::make('rimdetails', compact($rimdetails));
    }
```

and getting the error :
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\rimdetails' not found

Comment: in my blade file, which is called "rimdetails.blade.php" i link to it like this : href="{{ url('rimdetails', [$rim->RimID]) }}". My controller is called "RimsController". that is where i have the code that i pasted in the thread. the controller file is in app/Http/Controllers/RimsController.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

for laravel 6

```
 Route::get('rims','App\Http\Controllers\RimDetails@show');
```

for laravel 8

```
use App\Http\Controllers\RimDetails';
 Route::get('rims',[RimDetails@show,'show']);
```

and also make sure you have exact name of file as you have in controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias this `rimdetails` class if you want to reference it correctly. Currently you are in a declared namespace and referencing a class, `rimdetails`. PHP thinks you are referring to a class named `rimdetails` in the current namespace `App\Http\Controllers` so its looking for `App\Http\Controllers\rimdetails` as per the error.

Add this below the namespace declaration and before the class definition:

```
use App\rimdetails;
```

Assuming your model is in the `app` folder.